# LDAP over SSL Unsuccessful on 2003 DC, Working on 2008 R2 DC in Same Domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, ldap

I have a publicly signed UCC for LDAP over SSL in a test domain. It contains the Server Authentication OID Extension and works fine on a 2008 R2 DC in the same domain. The CSR was generated on the 2008 R2 Server, but contains a subject name matching the FQDN of the domain and SANs for the 2008 R2 DC's FQDN and the 2003 DC's FQDN.

When I attempt to connect from another system on the domain via ldp.exe to the 2008 R2 DC via port 636 with SSL, it works fine. However, connecting to the 2003 DC returns:

```
-----------
0x0 = ldap_unbind(ld);
ld = ldap_sslinit("testdc01", 636, 1);
Error 0 = ldap_set_option(hLdap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
Error 81 = ldap_connect(hLdap, NULL);
Server error: <empty>
Error <0x51>: Fail to connect to afgtestdc01.
ld = ldap_sslinit("testdc01", 636, 1);
Error 81 = ldap_set_option(hLdap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
Error 81 = ldap_connect(hLdap, NULL);
Server error: <empty>
Error <0x51>: Fail to connect to testdc01.
```

I have raised the [SChannel logging level](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260729) to "Log informational and success events", the most verbose level available. However, the only event when attempting to connect is `36867: Creating an SSL server credential`.

To avoid [a known issue where an incorrect certificate may be selected by SChannel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321051), I ensured the certificate is the only one in the Computer's local personal store. I moved the intermediate and root CAs to their respective computer stores. The certificate shows as valid in MMC.

What am I missing?

**Update:** Per the CA's recommendation, I've created a duplicate certificate with the Subject Name matching the FQDN of the server, as opposed to matching it in the SAN. This did not yield any better results.

However, `netstat -n -p tcp` does not show 636 as listening, though portqry from another 2003 server returns that 636 is listening. I am looking into why this may be.

I have also tried testing with ldp.exe on the 2003 DC itself, and I still cannot connect.

Comment: Could it be the encryption type? 2003 does not support a lot of newer ones with out hotfix/patching. Although when I've seen this it shows the cert as invalid on the 2003 box...

Comment: Ensure the cert is loaded in the local computer store and nowhere else. See: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6fd59e48-9954-42a3-9147-1343f0ad93df/need-help-troubleshooting-ldap-over-ssl-on-ad-lds-member-server

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins, when 2003 can't support the encryption, it will say so. The certificate definitely shows as valid.

Comment: @NathanC, I verified it is only loaded in this location.

Comment: @Tohuw Depends on how you are adding them. I ran into this by pushing a cert out from a 2008R2 DC (where it was valid). It did show up on the clients, it just did not work.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins Interesting. I've re-imported the certificate using the .cer format. The only somewhat non-standard thing I have done is request a 2048 bit key, but 2003 ought to be able to support that fine (I see no evidence it cannot)

Comment: For those stumbling across this, I never did fully resolve this, but a separate project removed this requirement in the test environment, so I stopped caring. If someone desperately needs this and is stuck, drop a comment and I can try to help with what I managed to grasp in my testing.